# Swift - Retrieving core data to custom cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, swift

I'm trying to retrieve core data and display it in a custom cell class. I think it will be easier if I present my code first.

This is my "original code", with a regular cell:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let CellID:NSString = "cell"

    var cell: UITableViewCell = self.tv.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellID) as UITableViewCell

    if let ip = indexPath as Optional {

        var data:NSManagedObject = myList[ip.row] as NSManagedObject

        cell.textLabel!.text = data.valueForKeyPath("username") as String!
    }

    return cell
}
```

This is what I change my code to when trying to use the custom cell:

```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let CellID:NSString = "cell"

        var cell: CustomCell = tv.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellID) as CustomCell

        if let ip = indexPath as Optional {

            var data:NSManagedObject = myList[ip.row] as NSManagedObject

            cell.titleLabel.text = data.valueForKeyPath("username") as String!
            cell.dateLabel.text = data.valueForKeyPath("date") as String!
        }

        return cell
    }
```

The first code works perfectly, but when using the second one I get the (lldb) runtime error.

Both "username" and "date" are saved as strings.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

EDIT:

Additional information:

```
var myList: Array<AnyObject> = []
```

The error that pops up is just "(lldb)" and "Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code = EXC_l386_BPT, subcode = 0x0)".

My model-file:

```
@objc(Model)
class Model: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var username: String
    @NSManaged var date: String
    @NSManaged var isAnonymousMessage: Bool

}
```

My cellForRowAtIndexPath-function:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let CellID:NSString = "cell"

    var cell: CustomCell = tv.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellID) as CustomCell

    if let ip = indexPath as Optional {

        let data = myList[indexPath.row] as Model

        cell.titleLabel.text = data.username
        cell.dateLabel.text = data.date
    }


    return cell
}
```

My viewDidAppear-function:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
    let freq = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Message")
    let en = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Message", inManagedObjectContext: context)

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Message")

    myList = context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as [Model]


    tv.reloadData()

}
```

my CustomCell class looks like this:

```
import UIKit

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!



    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()



        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Comment: What is `myList`? What is the error message that pops up?

Comment: Look into `NSFetchedResultsController`for creating a link between Core Data and UITableView

Comment: Are you sure that's an error an not just hitting a breakpoint? Is a line of code highlighted when the program stops? Which one?

Comment: @jrturton Yes, it's a breakpoint, sorry for calling it a error. As I wrote earlier, it says: "Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code = EXC_l386_BPT, subcode = 0x0)".

Comment: So, what line is the breakpoint on? Do you know what a breakpoint is?

Comment: @jrturton I'm familiar with it but not in xcode, so if you have a quick definition and don't mind sharing it I'm all ears.

Comment: Well is there a blue arrow in the side of your code, and a line of code highlighted in green when the program stops?

Comment: @jrturton Yes, it is.

Comment: @jrturton No that's not my problem, I thought maybe breakpoints had some other function in xcode, but I have not added a breakpoint in my code. There is no blue arrow besides my code. This is all really messy, I'm sorry. But I believe my error might be in my declaration of the cell, that's the only logical thing.

Comment: Your code doesn't just stop and go into the debugger unless it's either crashed or hit a breakpoint. You can't be helped unless you provide more information, and also accurately answer questions that people ask you.

Comment: For example, for the third time of asking, _which line is highlighted when the program stops_?

Comment: Yes, sorry for misunderstanding and misleading you. The app has crashed. It works fine when I'm using a regular cell. But when I use the custom class everything crashes. You can see the code above, so if there's nothing wrong with it I guess there's something I've forgotten to add in the CustomCell class. Or maybe there's just something I don't know about that needs to be done to connect the class. You've tried to help so I completely understand if you don't want to keep on going.

Comment: The line that is highlighted is the "let cell: CustomCell = self.tv.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellID) as CustomCell"

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to change your code a little bit.

Load your NSManagedObjects into an Array of your Core Data Class, for example like this:

```
 var myList = [ListObject]() // Where ListObject is your NSManagedClass

 let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "List")
 myList = context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as [ListObject]

// You should load this once (maybe in ViewDidLoad) so every Core Data object gets only fetched   once (you could easy refresh this if needed).
```

Then use in your cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
let data = myList[indexPath.row] as ListObject

cell.titleLabel.text = data.name
cell.dateLabel.text = data.date

// You dont need to use "valueForKeyPath" - just use the property as shown above.
```

Comment: Is "ListObject" the class that is names in my model-file? Should I still declare myList as "Array<AnyObject> = []"?

Comment: Yes. You should name it like your Model-File - so [YourModelClass]()

Comment: Okay. But in the last lines I get an error saying that "Model.username" and "Model.date" does not have those members.

Comment: So your "Modal" object is not type if your NSManagedClass. Provide some code.

Comment: How do you load your "Model" object in CellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: The last comment was a mistake by me, I wrote the "data.username" and "data.date" as you said, but now I get the excact same error that I got to start with.

Comment: Where do you load your data into myList? Show this Code too.

Comment: Is it possible there's something wrong in my Custom Cell class?

Comment: Try to print data.name - maybe there is another problem here (wrong assignment of titleLabel and dateLabel)

Comment: Yes, I think that would be a more likely problem, I've tried loading both the date and the username in the regular cell, and that works fine, but as soon as the custom cell is involved I get this error.

Comment: And your IBOutlets are correct? Your set in your Cell the specific Custom Class?

Answer (score 2):

```
var cell: CustomCell = tv.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellID) as CustomCell
```

Crashing on this line means that you're not getting a `CustomCell` back when you dequeue from the tableview.

You need to register the class with that reuse identifier, either by setting it in the storyboard or xib, or calling `registerClass(_ cellClass: AnyClass, forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String)` on the table view, normally in view did load.

If you've added a new cell to the storyboard and want to use it instead of the default one, make sure the reuse identifier is set correctly.

Comment: Thank you, that resolved this issue. Now this badboy showed up:            "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)" In lines: "cell.titleLabel.text = data.username"
       and "cell.dateLabel.text = data.date"

Comment: That sounds like the outlets aren't connected for your custom cell.

Comment: Okay, then I'm blank, I've just dragged and dropped the labels in the cell to the CustomCell class. Is there anything extra that needs to be done?

Comment: Select your cell in the storyboard and choose the connections inspector. Are the titleLabel and dateLabel outlets visible, and do they show the correct label when you select them? It honestly sounds like you need to go over some basic tutorials or something.

Comment: Yes, they are connected, and yeah, learning by doing is not always the most effective way of doing it, sorry about that. And this is also really frustrating, so I appreciate you being patient with me.